How to import character
This is Lolly Poppings. She are Czech and tough. Czechs are analytic, prize friendship and drink the most beer.
I created her in 3D with Blender to export her to Akeytsu. This is a 3D animation software and I am going to create a animation with Lolly Poppings.
When I export and import her to Akeytsu things get messed up. How do I export her successfully as she looks in Blender?
I searched after how to do this on other sites but I didn't found any information to how. There is no other solution then you telling me how to solve this. I post screenshots and my file so be gentle and solve this. Blunder you mean that i don't need other export settings. The mesh need retopology and will after not be messed up in Akeytsu. The retopology i did make the mesh lose colour. How do i keep this from happening? I duplicate vertex's because i am not able to mirror things with mirror modifier. How do you create a right part of a left part with mirror modifier?
Blend file:




Reference Image
Model in Blender









Blender Screenshot 2:

Blender Screenshot 3:

Blender Export Settings:

Akeytsu Screenshot:


Hi there! You did a great job to match the reference. But the mesh is in a very poor state. It's really broken and has everything a good clean mesh shouldn't have. It has holes, inverted normals, overlapping and intersecting faces, wires (=loose edges with no faces), duplicated vertices, and no edge flow at all. It's also a nightmare to work with. You need to do a retopology first to create a mesh with nice topology
